# Mapping metadata with avconv does not work

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, conversion, options, tagging

The way I understand `man avconv` (version `9.16-6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1`), the following command should convert `input.ogg` to `output.mp3` and carry over metadata:

```
avconv -i input.ogg -map_metadata 0 output.mp3
```

It does not, however; `ogginfo` clearly shows the information (artist, album, title, ...) in `input.ogg` and `id3info` confirms that `output.mp3` has empty (ID3) tags.

The same happens when converting `ogg` to `flac`, or (presumably) any combination of the formats.

Is my understanding of `-map_metadata` wrong? Is there a way to convert between formats and keep tags (without hardcoding like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10186/17409))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21496975) on Stack Overflow, I tinkered around and found out that the correct parameter depends on the combination of input and output format/codec.

These combinations work as intended:

- OGG → MP3: `-map_metadata 0:s:0`
- FLAC → MP3: `-map_metadata 0:g:0`
- FLAC → OGG: `-map_metadata 0`
  <sup>Using `-codec libvorbis`.</sup>

  In case your FLACs contains covers (as stream), add `-vn` to drop that stream (*all* video streams, really); the result is otherwise a broken file¹. See [here](https://superuser.com/q/169151) for ways to add cover images back in later.

Since `avconv` is officially dead now, I'll note that the same options seem to work with `ffmpeg` (at least up to 3.4.8).

---

1. According to *some* players, anyway. easyTag would log, "Ogg bitstream contains unknown data", and Android 12 would refuse to play the file, *but* VLC would see nothing wrong. So YMMV.